# Log4j2 using {} against using %d or %s

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

In Log4j2, are both the following equally efficient and do not cause any string concatenation with a log level more specific than DEBUG ? And for any reason/situation will one be preferred over other ?

```
log.warn(String.format("Number of cars : %d",carCount));
log.warn("Number of cars : {}",carCount );
```

And does {} works with any type of Object ?

Comment: Now with the separate `String.format` that one will be called always, won't it? Still curious about the original question, though.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend using the second appoach as it does not rely on type. E.g. for the first approach, you might get an `exception` if you are passing a stiring to a decimal parametet (e.g. `%d`).
@BoristheSpider corrected the comment.

Comment: @Andy897 no, just that `FomatterLogger` should only be used in exceptional circumstances. It hardcodes the log format and may cause expensive methods to be eagerly called (unless used with the [Java 8 `Supplier` formutaion](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#debug(org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier...))). You are much better sticking to the simple `{}` format and only ever passing in references to the method call, never the results of calling methods.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132625/discussion-on-question-by-andy897-log4j2-using-against-using-d-or-s).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `{}` notation is much more efficient than the `%s %d` String format notation. (There are [benchmarks](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-perf-test/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/perf/jmh/FormatterLoggerBenchmark.java) for this, I'll add some numbers later.)

The `{}` notation accepts any Object or primitive value, where the `%s %d ...` String format requires that the type of the parameter matches the format or an exception is thrown. So generally, `{}` is more convenient.

There are cases where you want to use the String format syntax, since it gives you very fine-grained control over the formatting. If you want to "pretty-print" a large number as `1,234,567.123`, or control the number of digits behind the decimal point, then `{}` is not enough.

Log4j2 allows you to mix both usages. It is possible to use the String format syntax everywhere (by using `LogManager.getFormattedLogger`), but perhaps more convenient is to use the default `{}` format most of the time, and only use the String format syntax when you need the fine grained control with the `printf` method:

```
logger.printf(Level.INFO, "Logging in user %1$s with birthday %2$tm %2$te,%2$tY", user.getName(), user.getBirthdayCalendar());
```

Internally, with the `{}` format Log4j2 makes an effort to avoid creating Strings or other temporary objects. This is not possible with the String format syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot Remko for such a elaborate response. Just one more quick question.  Can using {} throw a runtime exception in any scenario. ?

Comment: This may not be right place to ask/say this. .. but can you please suggest how can I follow up on this - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1768 . My follow up I mean at least the confirmation that problem is there or not :)

Comment: By default Log4j will swallow exceptions. You can configure each Appender to propagate exceptions to the caller by setting `ignoreExceptions="false"`. See appender docs.

Comment: Oh ok. But is it a good practice to propagate exceptions to the caller, in general ? Or one should let Log4j swallow it ?

Comment: Exceptions mean that your log statement did not get logged. For audit logging that fails the requirements. For debug logging you may not want to interrupt your app's business logic... So it depends on what you want.

Comment: I think most people would expect the logger library to never throw an exception which is why that's the default behavior.

Comment: For the JIRA best follow up on the JIRA ticket or mailing list.

Comment: I wouldn't call the `{}` option "more convenient" since `%s` provides the exact same functionality and is just as easy to write. It is, however, better in performance.

Comment: The reason I consider `{}` more convenient is that it doesn’t require any knowledge of the format specifier syntax, not even that `%s` is the equivalent of `String.valueOf()` and works for values of all types as well as `null` values. It requires fewer brain cycles. Perhaps “simpler” would be a better word.