# lambda and log4j2 style and performance - java

Tags: performance, lambda, java-8, log4j2

with using lambda I have found two style of logging for log4j2

```
logger.trace("Number is {}", () -> getRandomNumber());
```

and Second

```
logger.trace(()-> String.format("Number is  : %s)", getRandomNumber()));
```

What is the best style to write log statement with respect to performance ?

Answer (score 1):

Both versions should be same when `trace` is not enabled. For actual logging first version should be slightly faster, message templates used by both Log4j and SLF4j are more limited but parse faster than String.format( see [Log4j2 using {} against using %d or %s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532840/log4j2-using-against-using-d-or-s) ). Inlining message format with:

```
logger.trace(() -> "Number is " +getRandomNumber());
```

is fastest but it is bad style, unless there is only one argument, at the end of message.